# Export my Rails site to Phonegap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cordova

I want to use Phonegap for create light cellular version of my site.

Is there any way to save all my HTML`s and assets (after merge all the partials, create the entire assets pipeline items and convert haml and coffees to html and javascript)?

I want to use Rails for writing my client side code and save it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the site - if it is mostly static content it should work, but any user interaction will need to be built knowing that the server won't be there when the app runs. Using rails as a compiler for something designed as a phonegap app will work a lot better than trying to package an existing website.

Actually generating the static site is easy enough though:

```
wget -m -nH www.example.com
```